# Как сделать, что-бы в div блоке ссылкой было все, кроме одной цифры

Tags: html, link, href

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```
<a href="ссылка">
 <div>
  <img src></img>
   <p>1</p>

   // Не ссылка Begin
   <p>2</p>
   // Не ссылка End

   <p>3</p>
 </div>
</a>
```

Мне нужно что-бы весь блок div был ссылкой, кроме `<p>2</p>` что-бы пользователь мог выделить цифру 2, а еще лучше, скопировать данные (цифру 2) не переходя по ссылке, подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: При чем тут php? И что значит скопировать данные?

Comment: Что-бы при нажатии копировалась информация в буфер обмена, находящаяся в <p> в 7 строчке кода

Comment: Разделить `<a>` на несколько, да и всё, не? Хотя возможность этого зависит от конкретных стилей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) { debugger
  if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    e.target.select();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
p { display: inline; }
input { all: inherit; display: inline; width: 1ch; }
```

```html
<a href="ссылка">
  <div>
    <img>
    <p>1</p>
    <input type=text readonly value=2>
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Первый скрипт это какой язык программирования? И тогда сразу второй:)

Comment: javascript, css, html. вероятно, без инпута тоже можно тем же способом - это я перемудрил.